# squish startApplication() won't start an application with space

Tags: squish

I have an application with a space in the name of the application. Is it possible to start the application using squish's startApplication() function?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the link below. Squish documentation refers to many possible way to connect to an AUT. You can map your application on the AUT settings and call the application without space while running your test case.

Reference Link: https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rg-autsettings.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I actually have my AUT mapped but in order to invoke the AUT I should call it with the same name with the startApplication() function right? and so this method doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please paste the startApplication() command that you use in full to allow for debugging? Also the Runner/Server Log contains further information. Also try to explain what "does not work" means, what symptoms you see, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When the application/binary name contains a space please enclose it in double quotes, startApplication('"my aut name"').